# Mensaje de confirmar cuando refresco la pagina

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un formulario en una tabla que cuando ingreso los valores lo hace perfectamente y en la siguiente tabla se actualizan y se muestran los nuevos datos pero me di cuenta que **al aplastar F5** sale este mensaje como si guardara en cache o algo pero cuando le doy a aceptar se ingresa nuevamente y si aplasto F5 de nuevo vuelve a salir el mensaje ayuda por favor
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi script donde hago la recarga de las tablas y la limpieza de los inputs.

**Controlador PHP donde está el código script:**

```
if ($respuesta == "ok") {
    echo '<script>
            $("#formulario").on("submit", function (e) {
                tabla.ajax.reload();
                tabla2.ajax.reload();
                limpiar();
            });
    </script>';
}
```

**Este es mi Javascript donde limpio los inputs:**

```
function limpiar() {
    $("#codigoOrdenTrabajo").val("");
    $("#seleccionarUsuario").val("");
    $("#seleccionarDefecto").val("");
    $("#seleccionarCalificacion").val("");
    $("#observacion").val("");
}
limpiar();
```

Comment: Si presionas el **F5** y le das aceptar al mensaje mete el registro de nuevo? o te vuelve a mostrar el mensaje nuevamente.

Comment: lo ingresa nuevamente compa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a suponer que tienes un **form** con los **input** y el **botón** de guardar para enviar dicho formulario.

Si quieres que tus registros se actualicen correctamente sin la necesidad de enviar dicho formulario de manera normal, lo tienes que enviar con algún otro método en **Javascript**, ya que básicamente tu navegador lo que está haciendo al momento de que tú le das F5 es reenviar el formulario que acababas de mandar recientemente.

Entonces tomando en cuenta que tienes tu página con tus 2 tablas y el pequeño formulario lo que tendrías que hacer en lugar que el **form** tenga un **action**, lo vas a dejar simplemente con un **id**.

```
<form id="formulario">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
  <button type="button" id="enviar">Click Me!</button>
</form>
```

Tu código **PHP** lo vas a tener para únicamente recibir los datos del formulario y procesarlos (insertarlos en la bd). Desde PHP no vas a regresar ningún dato, ya que para eso tienes tus **DataTables**.

Como estas haciendo uso de **jQuery** lo más simple que puedes hacer es:

```
$(document).on("click", "#enviar", function (e) {
    let fname = $('#fname').val();
    let lname = $('#lname').val();
    $.post("actiondetuform.php", {name: fname, last: lname}, function (data) {
        tabla.ajax.reload();
        tabla2.ajax.reload();
        document.getElementById("formulario").reset();
    });
});
```

Tomando en cuenta que yo estoy usando como ejemplo **first name** y **last name** (tu lo haces con tus datos), solo le digo que cuando ocurra el evento **click** en el boton con **id** enviar, entonces setea los valores de **fname** y **lname** en las **variables** que tienen el mismo nombre. Seguido hacemos un `$.post()` a la url que tenia el **action** de tu **form**, le pasamos como parametro la **data** que son el **fname** y **lname**.

Después de que se enviaron todos los datos a esa url, hacemos el `ajax.reload()` de tus tablas y reseteamos el formulario.

Cabe mencionar que en **PHP** recibirás los valores con `$_POST` y los procesaras para insertarlos en la base de datos.